# how can i get selected value in jquery auto suggest plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here i'm using a auto-suggest plugin,

i'm facing a problem with getting the selected value.

```
var data = {items: [
{value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
{value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
{value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
{value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
{value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
{value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
]};

$("#search_query_top").autoSuggest(data.items, {
    selectedItemProp: "name",
    selectionLimit: 1, 
    searchObjProps: "name",
    startText: "Search by name,",
    resultClick: function(items){ console.log(items);}
});
```

Please, Can any one help me regarding this,

[Here is the documentation for plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

[Similar Question from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417022/how-to-get-value-of-autosuggest-plugin?rq=1)

Thanks

Comment: You can try items.value

Comment: Yup, try something like $("search_query_top").val(); and tell us what is the result

Comment: no it is not working...

Comment: @Okazari it is showing undefinned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for you :

```
//this will store all the results.
var mySearchResult = {};
$("#search_query_top").autoSuggest(data.items, {
    selectedItemProp: "name",
    selectionLimit: 3, 
    searchObjProps: "name",
    startText: "Search by name,",
    //each time i add a new item, i store it in the mySearchResult object
    selectionAdded: function(item){mySearchResult[(item.clone().find("a").remove().end().text())] = true},
    //each time i remove an item, i delete if from mySearchResult and i remove the item from the visual.
    selectionRemoved: function(item){delete mySearchResult[(item.clone().find("a").remove().end().text())]; item.remove();}
});

$('#sbmButton').click(function(e){

    var tab = [];
    for(var k in mySearchResult){
        tab.push(k); 
    }

    alert(tab.join("\n"));

});
```

A last bug still appear, the very first item you add is not removed from the display list items.

You can check this on this [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UEVMj/16/).
I'll try to see what's going on about the little bug.

Hope it helped you.

EDIT : Check out the other answer that find a more "friendly" way to do the same things. You'll have to do some changes, but i think this is the best way.
I really find this plug-in a bit tricky for finding this values. Finally i don't recommend this one.

Answer (score 1):

add `asHtmlID: 'aaaaa'` in `.autoSuggest()`

In `$('#sbmButton').click()`, add `console.log($('#as-values-aaaaa').val())`

Comment: Great ! This is much more simple. When you use "asHtmlID: 'aaaaa' as an option, a new div is created (that is not created without the option) with as value all the key separated by a coma.